# Express js, GET request to the same route for the second time always pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am developing an express application in which I need to render a landing page for '/' route. This page has a text box and a button. When user adds text to textbox and hits submit button I need to make request to same url but with text added as its query parameter. This request will render a new page whose contents depend upon query text.

Now what is happening is when user enters text into textbox and presses button, form makes GET request and route looks something like `http://localhost:3000/?q=abc`. I can see this request as pending in network tab of chrome developer tools but this request never reaches server. I cannot see any request for `/?q=abc` in server console.

If I restart server and then open `http://localhost:3000/?q=abc`, proper contents get loaded in browser. But if I change url back to `http://localhost:3000`, I can see pending request in network tab and this request never reaches server.

My code looks something like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.query.q) 
    res.render('results.ejs');
  else
    res.render('landing.ejs')
});
```

Any idea why no call to server is being made? I have spent whole day trying to figure out reason for this behavior. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the first response never finishes. Try giving your render a callback `function(err, html){}` then see if `err` is not null.

Comment: Have you tried inserting temporary middleware to see where exactly the request gets stuck in your middleware/route chain? It sounds like there is a middleware somewhere that is not calling `next()` in some situation.

Comment: Could you try to replace `res.render('results.ejs');` by `res.render('results');` and `res.render('landing.ejs')` by `res.render('landing')`

Comment: @mscdex: You are right, one of my middleware was not calling `next()` sometimes. This middleware makes an http request to some other api synchronously. Whenever remote api is down, `next()` from this middleware was not getting called. Handling this situation solved my issue. You can add this as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried inserting temporary middleware to see where exactly the request gets stuck in your middleware/route chain? It sounds like there is a middleware somewhere that is not calling `next()` in some situation.